# Forbid specific variable access from global scope

Tags: php, oop, global-variables, php-5.3

Is there a way to forbid a variable from being picked out of global scope?

Something like:

```
#index.php
$forbidden = 'you should not be able to access me outside this scope'; // maybe invoke a function or namespaces?
require 'stuff.php';
echo new stuff();

#stuff.php
class stuff
{
    public function __toString()
    {
        global $forbidden; // to result in an error or something?
        /*
            just a random example, but yes, any way
            to somehow make a variable not global?
        */
        return 'I am forbidden';
    }
}
```

Have no idea if it's possible, but anyways, interested in OOP only fashion.

#### Reason?

To disallow a specific class from being instantiated into a variable and then taken out from global scope to reuse it's functions. Make class completely "private", kind of like a master class that does all the automation.

Hope I've made myself clear.

Comment: I don't think there is a way to do this without a `debug_backtrace()` which is terribly expensive. This sounds fairly esoteric though - do you have a specific reason to forbid this on code level? Instead of just defining it as a coding rule?

Comment: Well, if there's one class that automatically creates the page routine. Like, 1) looking if the request is valid, 2) getting all the needed stuff and 3) automatically render it all out. Allow application modification only with libraries and plugins, that cannot globally access this variable/class to start a loop. I could go with not defining it as variable at all, but there should be a way to let 3rd party developer to enforce request with debugging/profiling stuff pre-master class execution. (in short)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only way I can think of would be to "fake" global scope...

```
//index.php
function scope() {
    require 'actual.php';
}
scope();
```

and now, putting code in actual.php looks like "normal" code but it actually is inside function scope. Obviously you can't declare functions or classes in actual.php now, but otherwise it behaves the same, with the exception that any variables declared will be in the function's scope instead of global scope.

I really wouldn't do this though. A beating with a stick usually works if someone does something stupid like globals like that ;)

Comment: Well, there are always those guys that simply doesn't abide by the rules, or do not understand the documentation or simply want to experiment. But interesting idea..

Comment: I like this answer. Don't pollute the global space in the first place. :)

Comment: @Tom If you're afraid of your co-workers breaking things -- they'll be able to break things no matter what you do.

Comment: Not that I'm afraid of people breaking things, but to simply keep the code clean. I bet 70% of the developers using a framework, use it wrong. Like, for instance, Symfony... They made the framework, documented it etc., random guy who thinks he's the PRO, avoids documentation, uses Symfony as a "extension" to write application in his own way. The application works, but huh, in the end it doesn't look like it needs Symfony, it needs just a PHP extension that would include some functionality of Symfony.

Comment: Well then, as Jani proposed: if you want to keep your code clean, don't pollute the global scope.

Comment: As I said, that's not me doing all that stuff, that's a potential somebody who would later use my application.

Comment: @Tom is it really our job as framework authors to protect programmers who don't read the manual from themselves?

Comment: The difference relies in framework for programmers and framework for everybody who can "read" not only "read code".